# Copy several rows to several columns

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a column of data with several rows (about 125000).

I want to copy that data, every 62 rows, to separate columns. So I would have from row 1 to 62 in column A, from row 63 to 125 in column B, from row 126 to 188 in column C and so on until there is no more data.

Is there an easy way to do this? Thank you so much in advance! (I'm new in matlab)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to provide mentions of research you have done so far or code that you have written to try to solve this on your own before bringing it to the group. You will find that SO users are far more likely to put in the effort to help you out when you show them that you have put in the effort to try to solve the problem too. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your matrix is 'a' and it's first dimention is a multiple of 62 (if not, add enough rows of some sort to make it so):

```
reshape(a',size(a,2)*62,size(a,1)/62);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `a` denote your column vector. If the number of elements of `a` is a multiple of 62:

```
result = reshape(a,62,[]);
```

If it's not: either fill `a` appropriately (as mentioned by @oliglio) or use [`vec2mat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html) (Communications Toolbox), which automatically does the filling with a specified value:

```
result = vec2mat(a,62,NaN).'; %'// or replace "NaN" by the desired fill value
```